# How to call data for tooltips in jQuery and JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I wanna call My `mob_num` data in Project_header Span`s tooltip

```
{ 
  'data': 'project_header',
  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<span  data-field="name" class="tool-tip" title=" '+ data +'  ">'
```

In this sector `'+ data +'` calls data of project_header correctly in the tooltip but I want to call `mob_ＮＵＭ` data in the `title` attribute.

The following is my Code

```
{ 'data': 'mob_num_header', 'orderable': true},
{ 'data': 'group_header', 'orderable': true},
{
  'data': 'project_header',
  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<span  data-field="name" class="tool-tip" title=" '+ data +'  ">' + data + '</span>';}
},
//{'data': 'project_header', 'orderable': true},
{ 'data': 'option_header', 'orderable': true},
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: is `mob_num` inside your `data`?, if so your might want to try `data.mob_num`. If not then please include the content of `data`

Comment: When I write data.mob_num It shows me undefined in tooltip

Comment: "columns": [
  {'data':'user_name_header','orderable': true},
  {'data':'mail_add_header','orderable': true},
  {'data':'mob_num_header','orderable': true},

  {'data': 'project_header',
       "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<span  data-field="name" class="tool-tip" title=" '+ data.mob_num_header +'  ">' + data + '</span>';}
       },
  //{'data':'project_header','orderable': true},
  {'data':'option_header','orderable': true},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I did this .
I added this following code

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": 7,
        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            if (row.project_header != "") {
                return '<span href title="rabin :'+row.mob_num_header+'" data-toggle="tooltip">'+data+'</span>';
            }else {
                return row.project_header
            }
        }
```

This is a complete solution of this .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm wrong or I didn't fully understood the question, but you could try doing an `if()` statement to select the one `data` that is `mob_num`.

Like this:

```
var myDataMob = "";

if (data.data == "mob_num_header") myDataMob = data.data;
```

Comment: Can you please define me where should I enter this code in my code .

Comment: I am a beginner so its little difficult to understand me .

Comment: You wanna select the `data` witch contains `mob_num_header`, right?

Comment: I have called data from above code `{ 'data': 'mob_num_header', 'orderable': true},
{ 'data': 'group_header', 'orderable': true},
{
  'data': 'project_header',
  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<span  data-field="name" class="tool-tip" title=" '+ data +'  ">' + data + '</span>';}
},
//{'data': 'project_header', 'orderable': true},
{ 'data': 'option_header', 'orderable': true},`

Comment: Now This code are perfect going but I want this { 'data': 'mob_num_header', 'orderable': true}, data to show as the title of {
  'data': 'project_header',
  "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<span  data-field="name" class="tool-tip" title=" '+ data +(here is mob_num_header )'  ">' + data + '</span>';}
}, this section .

Comment: Very much thank you to #Santiago Torrabadella for giving your time and I am sorry  as I am not a native English speaker so I couldn`t explain you . Finally I did It

Comment: It's fine! We are all here to help and ask for help. Glad to hear you found a solution.